# Writing abstract

Tags: publications, journals, writing, abstract, linguistics

I want to submit an abstract for a call for papers for a good journal in my field. I don't have the paper ready yet, but I have a vague idea for a paper that I would like to propose to the journal editors. Is it possible to write an abstract on such a basis? If selected, there is time of 7 months to submit the manuscript.

Comment: What field? Scientific? Math? History? ...?

Comment: Applied Linguistics

Comment: This may not be the best site for this question, given the field. Not many linguists are regular here. There is a companion site that might be better: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/. Check their help center before posting, though. But I've added a tag to try an ping whoever is about.

Comment: Indeed this could be very field-specific, but I suspect the answer is: **you can always try**. It's just an abstract, and it can be changed by the time the paper is ready.

Comment: What is your confidence level of being able to complete a paper of acceptable quality in the time? What is the penalty if you don't?

Comment: @BillOnne it will be rejected.

Comment: @stochastic Yes, thank you for that uplifting comment. No harm in trying!

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for your comment :)